# How to make application UISlider snappy?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is how I am currently doing it

```
- (IBAction)sliderDistanceChanged {
    CGFloat sliderPosition = self.sliderDistance.value;
    NSUInteger sliderIndex = [BGDistanceFilterStop indexForFilterEffect:sliderPosition];

    self.distanceFilterForCatalog = @([BGDistanceFilterStop numberValueOfDistance:sliderIndex]);
    //self.distanceFilterForCatalog= @(self.sliderDistance.value).roundWithForDistanceFilter;
    //[self.distanceFilter setTitle:self.distanceFilterForCatalog.distanceForm forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.distanceFilter setTitle:[BGDistanceFilterStop stringValueOfDistance:sliderIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
- (IBAction)SliderNoLongerTouched:(id)sender {
    CGFloat sliderIndex = [BGDistanceFilterStop sliderSnappedPosition:self.sliderDistance.value];
    self.sliderDistance.value=sliderIndex;
}
```

Basically it detects self.sliderDistance.value and then based on that set the reported value after rounding.

Once the user no longer touch, I change the position of self.sliderDistance.value

That is fine.

However, I want to change the self.sliderDistance.value before the user touch up. However, it's the same variable iOS uses to track both hand position and value of slider.

So how do I arrange that the button snap to the right place without changing the self.sliderDistance.value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
(IBAction)sliderDistanceChanged {
    CGFloat sliderPosition = self.sliderDistance.value;
    NSUInteger sliderIndex = [BGDistanceFilterStop indexForFilterEffect:sliderPosition];

    self.distanceFilterForCatalog = @([BGDistanceFilterStop numberValueOfDistance:sliderIndex]);
    //self.distanceFilterForCatalog= @(self.sliderDistance.value).roundWithForDistanceFilter;
    //[self.distanceFilter setTitle:self.distanceFilterForCatalog.distanceForm forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.distanceFilter setTitle:[BGDistanceFilterStop stringValueOfDistance:sliderIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
- (IBAction)SliderNoLongerTouched:(id)sender {
    CGFloat sliderIndex = [BGDistanceFilterStop sliderSnappedPosition:self.sliderDistance.value];
    self.sliderDistance.value=sliderIndex;
}
```

Basically it detects `self.sliderDistance.value` and then based on that set the reported value after rounding.

Once the user no longer touch, I change the position of `self.sliderDistance.value`

That is fine.

Ho

Comment: What is the relevance of the image?

Comment: @JimThio - this _newly-accepted-answer_ from a 3-year-old question is just a repeat of the question? With a nice-but-irrelevant image?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that each of these actions is linked to the UISlider in question. The first is triggered by `valueChanged` and the second by `touchUpInside`.

In this case firstly change your signatures to these

```
- (IBAction)sliderDistanceChanged:(UISlider*)sender;
- (IBAction)sliderNoLongerTouched:(UISlider*)sender;
```

so that you can refer to the slider with `sender` instead of `self.sliderDistance` (simpler, more self-contained).

Modify `sliderDistanceChanged`

```
    - (IBAction)sliderDistanceChanged:(UISlider*)sender;
          //allocate the raw slider value to a variable
          CGFloat rawValue = sender.value; 

          //calculate the snapped value
          CGFloat snappedValue = [BGDistanceFilterStop sliderSnappedPosition:sender.value];

          //snap the slider in position
          sender.value = snappedValue;


         //now do the rest of your processing 
         //using rawValue if you want the raw value, 
         //snappedValue if you want the snapped value

       }
```

Simplify `sliderNoLongerTouched`

```
 - (IBAction)sliderNoLongerTouched:(id)sender {
    sender.value = [BGDistanceFilterStop sliderSnappedPosition:sender.value];
}
```

(you don't actually need this now, as the value snaps in place in `sliderDistanceChanged`)

Comment: Works perfectly. Pretty snappy now.